MacOS Sequoia: How to programatically test the calling application has "Local Network" permission?
I maintain several C++/Qt apps whose purpose is to interact with devices on the LAN (via the TCP and UDP features of the BSD sockets API).
They generally work fine under MacOS, but Apple in its wisdom has added a "Local Network" permission to its "Security and Privacy" settings pane, and if the apps aren't listed and enabled there, then they appear to the user to be broken and I get a bug report from an irritated user.
Therefore, what I would like to do is have my apps explicitly test for the state of this permission on startup, so that if they don't have that permission enabled I can show a dialog with explicit instructions to the user about what the problem is and how to enable Local Network permission.
My question is, how can I explicitly test for the presence/absence of this permission from within my app?  (I can of course do a sort-of-test by trying to send/receive data over the local network and seeing if it works, but I'd prefer to check for the permission setting directly since guessing its state from related network behavior is likely to cause misdiagnoses in some scenarios).

Looks like the answer is no https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650648

@AlanBirtles can you point to the exact post within that thread you are referring to?  There are a lot of posts there.  (The post that says "it can't be done" doesn't count :) )

So, the actual Apple employee saying "you can't do this" doesn't count?

No, that's a non-solution.  He does later on mention that the Bonjour APIs will return kDNSServiceErr_PolicyDenied in this scenario, so I'm going to look in to doing something with that, and if it works I'll post an answer here.

(sorry, I see now that I initially misread your original comment as Looks like the answer is *on*, which isn't quite the same thing)

FWIW, I couldn't get the NWBrowser and Bonjour/kDNSServiceErr_PolicyDenied approaches mentioned in the above link to work -- that is, they didn't produce an error message, even when my app has Local Network access denied.  So for now my code just makes do with a heuristic:  It tries to send a test multicast IPv6 packet on each (non-loopback) network interface, and if it can't send on any of them, it shows an error dialog suggesting that Local Network access may need to be granted and giving steps for how to do that.
